# Can't push lever to shift into big ring, lever will not move all the way

Tags: derailleur

I just installed a new 6800 groupset on my bike for the first time, and everything went O.K except for the front derailleur. I can't shift it into the big ring, if I push the lever to change to the big ring, it won't go all the way, and it won't make a click.

If I push just the smaller lever (to get into the small ring) it makes a click just fine, but if I push the big lever, it will move a bit but not enough to click.

If I disconnect the cable from the FD, I still can't get the lever to move and make a click. Is the cable stuck somewhere?

Comment: when you fitted the new kit, did you also replace the cables? inner? outer?

Comment: Everything was brought brand new new. Brand new cables, albeit reusing the outers (however they are only just over 6 months old).

Comment: That you have the problem even when the cable is disconnected suggests to me that it is not the derailleur, but either the shifter or the cable or the way the cable has been fitted. That the cable is new would tend to eliminate the cable. I'd be tempted to take the cable out of the shifter completely and start over.

Comment: With the cable disconnected from the shifter, should the shifter make clicks when pushing the lever (as if changing from each chain ring)? Because I've disconnected the cable, pulled it back out of the bike, so now it's like I first got it (http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ed9F1S3KL._SX466_.jpg) But if I push the big lever, it won't make a click noise.

Comment: it is a while since I toyed with my shifters but my memory is that they should definitely click, regardless of whether they're connected to the FD (or RD). But you can test this using the other shifter, no? Or, with the old shifter? I can;t imagine that particular shifter would work differently.

Comment: The old one does click without a cable. So I pulled out the cable completely and re-threaded it, looks like it is working now. The cable was pre-installed from the factory and it appears it wasn't in correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the limit screws -- if you set them in the wrong way they might stop the full movement of the cage, irrespective of the cable.  If the cable is disconnected and if you cannot move the cage so that the chain goes on the front outer right that is either because of limit screws or the bottom bracket is so far out the outer ring cannot be reached by the cage.

Check out this page and see whether you get something out of it:

[Park Tool front derailleur adjustment](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment)

PS as PeteH mention in his comment, if you cannot 'click' the levers, check whether you have installed the cable correctly -- I personally think this is a very unlikely situation, because cables can normally be installed only when the shifter is in one specific position.  Worth a check though.

Comment: but the Op says that the shifter does not pull enough cable to "click" even when _not connected_ to the derailleur, so how can the limits on the derailleur be the problem?