# Not able to shift to largest Chain Ring - Lever not clicking, when cable is connected to FD

Tags: shifter, cable, derailleur-front

After installing Shimano TZ 30 Front Derailleur, **I am not able to shift from middle ring to big ring**. I can successfully shift Shifter from 1 to 2 and even from 2 to 1. But not from 2 to 3.

**If I disconnect the cable then Shifter clicks properly from 2nd to 3rd and 3rd to 2nd.**

My Guess is that the tension is too high in the cable.

*Question is related to a previous unansewered question [Can't push lever to shift into big ring, lever will not move all the way](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/cant-push-lever-to-shift-into-big-ring-lever-will-not-move-all-the-way). But with me the Shifter clicks when I disconnect the cable.*

Comment: See if you can, with your hand, force the derailer to the big ring position.  If you can then likely the cable is somehow fouled (could be rusted up, could bed badly routed).  If you can't then likely the "high limit" screw is screwed in too far, or possibly the derailer has become twisted on the seat tube.

Answer (score 2):

Before tightening(attaching) the cable at the derailleur end, make sure the you have released the shifter all the way.

Sounds like you may have had the shifter in 2nd position when you attached the cable, therefor you don't have enough cable 'left'. So without more details we can't tell whether you are shifting up or down.

In addition, when installing the cable be sure that the cable-tension 'screw' at the shifter end is turned in (almost all the way).

An easy way to check your cable function (before attaching it to the derailleur) is to pinch it with you fingers, at the derailleur end, instead of tightening the cable nut. Now when you shift gear you will feel the cable pull your fingers in. If there isn't a smooth action, you know you have cable(or cable routing) issues. If the motion is OK, shift down all the way and you will feel the cable extend at your hand, then you tighten the nut.